# Simple and performant way to save public list of IPs into python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's a simple and performat way to save online published lists of IP addresses like [this one](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/) in a standard python list? Example

`ip_list = ['109.70.100.20','185.165.168.229','51.79.86.174']`

HTML parsing library beautifulsoap seems way to sophisticated for the simple structure.

Comment: Due to the formatting of this website, beautifulsoup would be a pretty easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that beautifulsoup is too sophisticated, its that the content type is text, not html. There are several APIs for downloading content, and `requests` is popular. If you use its `text` property, it will perform any decoding and unzipping needed

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/")
ip_list = resp.text.split()
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working fine. I thought it's not a file of type text because under the hood it's proper HTML …

Comment: Interesting. When i tested with `requests` I got a warning message about too many page accesses so just went off of my original download. I'll check it again.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked. `resp.headers['Content-Type']` was `'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'` and `resp.text` was just text.